# How to pack the C bit field struct via encoding package in GO?

Tags: c, go, encoding, bit, bit-fields

Except using cgo, Do you know what is the best way to pack the GO object to byte slice?

We can use encoding/binary package to serialize GO struct to byte slice as far as we know but it supports only fixed-length variable so cannot support following case.

```c
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t          foo:12;
    uint32_t          bar:9;
    uint32_t          baz:1;
    uint32_t          qux:10;
} type_t;
```

Do we need to implement GO struct with getter/setter for this case with terrible bit manipualtion considering endianness?
Such as:

```golang
type typeT struct
{
    fooBarBazQux uint32
}
// some complex bit manipulation considering endianness
func (t typeT) getFoo() uint32 {
}
func (t typeT) setFoo(val uint32) {
}
```

Is there any better solution for this?

I tried [encoding/json mashaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) for my custom type but encoding/binary package does not seem to support this kind of interface.

I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual packing and bit order of such structures in C is not guaranteed, and may vary from one compiler to the next, even on the same machine.<sup>1</sup>  If the bit order actually matters—as it will in this case—you should probably write your own setters and getters.

Go does have built in [binary encoding operations](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/), which can let you access binary data even if it's not stored in native machine order.  But you can open-code such accesses; they're not particularly complex.  Similarly, doing all the bit shifting and masking for insertion and access is not *difficult*, it's just a bit tedious.

Cgo does not support bitfield access.  Related (but no answer there): [How to access C bitfield in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56459197/1256452); [Go: Bitfields and bit packing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5793098/1256452) (no support for bitfields in cgo, and none planned).

---

<sup>1</sup>Back in the day, on the 680x0, this was a problem when switching from the MIT C compiler to the Sun one, as they used different bit orders within words.  When the 68020 introduced bitfield instructions, they numbered the bits differently from the earlier single-bit test instructions, which kind of encouraged this incompatiblity.  See also [Are later 68000 variants backward compatible with earlier ones?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6647/3464)